# Rails Active Admin form display based on checked booleans?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I've got a simple Active Admin form that is displaying a lot of form fields, but only some of the form fields will be needed if a boolean is checked on that record.  Is there a way to make those forms fields show up only if a boolean is clicked?  Is it possible to show forms based on if a cell has any information in it? For example, from my Active Admin page:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs do
    f.input :name
    f.input :active
    f.input :use_image  <---------------  this is a boolean
    if :use_image_boolean_is_clicked
       f.input :image_link  ## show form only after :use_image is clicked?
    end
    f.input :product_1  <---------------  this is a text field
    if :product_1_form_has_any_text_in_it 
       f.input :proudct_1_link  ## show form only after :product_1 has text in it?
    end
    f.input :product_2  <---------------  this is a text field
    if :product_2_form_has_any_text_in_it
       f.input :product_2_link  ## show form only after :product_2 has text in it?
    end
    f.input :text
    f.input :alt_text
 end
end
```

Thanks in advance for any and all help!